# What are the rules to eat non-veg?

Tags: scripture, non-vegetarian, meat

What are the rules to eat non-veg ?
In which shastra this rules where listed ?

Comment: There's no primary or very important rule. It is just that one **shouldn't** get attached to meat at any cost! Either you give up attachment through knowledge or meditation or you sacrifice your food to your Ishvara, but it the end **attachment to meat** shouldn't come! BUT, it is known to increase rajas guna, that is well known and you'd need a lot of struggle to avoid it. This is the primary and foremost thing. Secondly, various sects or sampradayas have own rules regarding how to sacrifice  - that is always secondary.

Comment: The only rule of eating meat is that the animal must have been lawfully sacrificed to the devas in acts of worship. Brahmavaivartapurāṇa in this regard gives a graphic statement - consuming water that hasn't been offered to Viṣṇu is equivalent to consuming urine, consuming food that hasn't been offered to Viṣṇu is akin to consuming faeces. A similar tone is emphasized in the Smṛti texts. However, Medhātithi, writes in his commentary of the Manusmṛti that such a rule applies only for ekantins & need not be applied in case of veg food in day-to-day life.

Comment: Ekāntin or ekāntabhaktas are described as hard-core devotees who outright refuse to worship other deities, refuse interaction with non-devotees & having made a vow to eat only prasāda throughout the rest of their lives & thus are directed to undergo more strict rules than other devotees.

Answer (score 0):

Foods consumed (consumables) are of three different types only (Satva Rajas Tamas) and not classified in general as Veg & Non-Veg.
Though many plants/flowers are Veg only - they carry non-Veg in them (like bugs & worms - example shore Cauliflowers).

DIVINE VERSES OF GOD say

A Human(advanced than animals & others) must eat patram, phalam, annam, aayasam and dravyam (dugdam).

But foods on Earth are also inhabited by DEMON spirits due to which many foods of various types are consumed by living beings.

```
          DERIVED ANSWER


         ACCEPTABLE NON-VEG
```

Manu Dharma says that humans can depend on animals for food if animals are fed well and if animals are ready to give humans food being grateful, but, both must have followed harmlessness. Otherwise the foods result in KARMA.

Thus, due to non availability of production of foods without harming animals, Non-Veg is banned in Hinduism & eater of such KARMIC food must undergo PRAAYASCHITTAM.